# Subset data.table containing groups with at least 2 non-NA values

Tags: r, data.table

In the `data.table` below, I want to subset only the groups (in
column `x`), which have at-least 2 non-NA values.

```
dt <- data.table(x = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3), rep("d", 3), rep("e", 4)), y = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA))
    x  y
 1: a NA
 2: a  1
 3: a  2
 4: a  3
 5: a NA
 6: b NA
 7: b  2
 8: b  3
 9: c  1
10: c  2
11: c  3
12: d NA
13: d NA
14: d  1
15: e  1
16: e  2
17: e NA
18: e NA
```

The correct solution is too slow on the large data sets.

```
dt[, .SD[sum(!is.na(y)) >= 2], by = "x"]
```

The alternate solution is fast, but I don't know how to put the condition to check for non-NA values.

```
dt[, if(.N >= 2L) .SD, by = "x"]
```

Here is the performance

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
      a = dt[, .SD[sum(!is.na(y)) >= 2], by = "x"],
      b = dt[, if(.N >= 2L) .SD, by = "x"],
      times = 100)
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
    a 1953.548 1977.380 2026.2570 2021.6775 2055.699 2276.247   100   b
    b  862.626  889.073  936.8346  906.7315  918.019 3744.886   100  a
```

Comment: Just to answer the part of your question on _"I don't know how to put the condition to check for non-NA values"_. One way would be to change `if(.N >= 2L)` to `if(sum(!is.na(y)) >= 2L)` or `if(.N-sum(is.na(y)) >= 2L)`.

Comment: Thanks, I answered this question below with similar logic.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen it before but I don't think your logic is right. see my reply to your answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72711598/10848898)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A faster option would be to get the index with `.I` and extract that row index

```
dt[dt[, .I[sum(!is.na(y)) >= 2], by = "x"]$V1]
```

-benchmarks

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
      a = dt[, .SD[sum(!is.na(y)) >= 2], by = "x"],
      b = dt[dt[, .I[sum(!is.na(y)) >= 2], by = "x"]$V1],

      times = 100)
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
    a 898.833 943.8020 1095.5831 1037.7235 1105.3080 4366.111   100
    b 516.667 579.7975  622.3739  613.9905  661.9465 1010.461   100
```

Answer (score 0):

The following turned out to be even faster -

```
dt[, if(length(na.omit(y)) >= 2) .SD, by = "x"]
```

Here are the performance results

```
    microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
      a = dt[, .SD[sum(!is.na(y)) >= 2], by = "x"],
      c = dt[dt[, .I[sum(!is.na(y)) >= 2], by = "x"]$V1],
      d = dt[, if(length(na.omit(y)) >= 2) .SD, by = "x"],
      times = 1000)

    Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
    a 1927.523 1967.3550 2063.7377 1991.9865 2093.7970 24554.46  1000   c
    c 1131.147 1163.5625 1291.7830 1196.6600 1245.2065 23912.77  1000  b
    d  888.337  916.1545  972.7813  927.0180  971.1625 25220.55  1000 a
```

Comment: I think that this `if(sum(y, na.rm = T) >= 2)` is a wrong logic if I did not misunderstand your question. Having `sum(y, na.rm = T) >= 2` satisfied does not imply that there is at least 2 non-missing values. example: If you have a group with four observations containing three missing values as in `c(NA, 3, NA, NA)`, then its sum when, removing NAs, will be greater than 2 while it actually contains less than two non-missing values.

Comment: Thanks, @Christian so much for pointing this out. I have fixed my answer to address this issue. Does it look right now?

Comment: Yes, it is right. Note that it's generally not a good idea/practice to base a benchmark on such a small dataset. It would be better to do it on a dataset that is quite similar to the dataset you are using in practice, and I guess that your dataset is larger than 18 rows. The number of evaluations is also too large. 5/10 is already enough.